# How to add a javascript transition to jquery expanding text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I've got a problem with creating a transition for a collapsing text-jquery plugin I've found. Unfortunatley I've go almost no understanding to javascript. At the bottom I added "&&(this).show('fast');" but it didn't work. Hopefully you can help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var maxheight=16;
  var showText="Weiterlesen";
  var hideText="Zusammenklappen";

  $('.expand').each(function () {
    var text = $(this);
    if (text.height() > maxheight){
        text.css({ 'overflow':'hidden','height': maxheight + 'px' });

        var link = $('<p class="weiter" id="noselect"><a>' + showText + '</a></p>');
        var linkDiv = $('<div></div>');
        linkDiv.append(link);
        $(this).after(linkDiv);

        link.click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (text.height() > maxheight) {
              $(this).html('<a>' + showText + '</p>');
              text.css('height', maxheight + 'px')
              &&(this).show('fast');
          } else {
              $(this).html('<a>' + hideText + '</p>');
              text.css('height', 'auto')
              &&(this).show('fast');
          }
        });
    }       
  });
```

});

Comment: Please remove the &&. It does not make sense to use it there

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing it to this

```
 $(this).html('<a>' + hideText + '</p>');
 text.css('height', 'auto');
 $(this).show('fast');
```

This is using the correct JQuery syntax, wether it works or not depends on what "this" is.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work. I've got a p-tag called .expand with much text inside of it. This tag has no styles. It's simply for identifying it in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
(this).show();
```

wont work. this is an *HTML Element* , and it has no *show* property. You want the jquerys object property.

```
jQuery(this)//get the jquery object of that html el
.show();//call the function on that
```

$ is just a shortform of jQuery. So:

```
$(this).show();
```

Note *this* is the link, but you want to show the text (wich is already a jquery object):

```
text.show();
```

---

Concerning the && ( the AND operator):

```
false && alert("nope");
true && alert("yes");
a() && b(); //b is just called if a() is truthy => can create bugs in your case
```

Ita not neccessary / useful to use this operator here. However, you could use the Comma operator, but its common to simply use two statements...

---

However, if ive got you right, its not neccessary to *show* but rather to add a transition. That can be done with css:

```
.expand{
 transition:all 2s ease;
}
```

*Note this doesnt work for height, but for max-height, so one may set height:auto and change max height from 0px to 500%...*

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Unfortunately the css style does not seem to do anything. Is there something I can do to help all of you understanding the problem?

Comment: @benny  i think theres a problem with height: auto and transitions. May look that up i bet theres another thread for it...

Comment: @benny voilá https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css